# How to do a collapsing multiselect in Bulma?

Tags: css, bulma

Bulma [has](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/select/#multiple-select) multiselect but it seems like it is always expanded. What I need is something like [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/#basic-example):
[image: Multiselect demo]

Is there any way?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Nope, I haven't